# Evaluating $\sum\limits_{x=1}^{2012} \frac{9^\frac{x}{2013}}{9^\frac{x}{2013}+3}$

Tags: summation

$\Large \sum\limits_{x=1}^{2012} \frac{9^\frac{x}{2013}}{9^\frac{x}{2013}+3}=?$

I thought that if $\Large\frac{9^k}{9^k+3}$ was equal to $\Large\frac{9^{1-k}}{9^{1-k}+3}$ it would be easy to solve but apparently it isn't.

Comment: Where did you find this? How do you know/why do you think there is a nice answer?

Comment: A friend asked me. He told me that the answer was 1005,25

Comment: @ZaferCesur, do you mean the summation has two values?

Comment: I meant 1005.25 but it was wrong anyway. Your solution is correct, thanks.

Comment: I get $1006$ as an answer?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

You are on the right way

If $\displaystyle f(k)=\frac{9^k}{9^k+3},$

$\displaystyle f(1-k)=\frac{9^{1-k}}{9^{1-k}+3}=\frac9{9+3\cdot9^k}=\frac3{9^k+3}$

$\displaystyle\implies f(k)+f(1-k)=1$

How many such pairs do we have ?